# Plot Stream Function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a streamline with a stream function.

[image]

I Used below code but its not working

```
syms R r Y y a a_bar pi Gamma;     
k=sqrt((4*r*R)/((y-Y)^2+(r+R)^2));
k_bar=sqrt((4*r*R)/((y+Y)^2+(r+R)^2));
[K1,E1]=ellipke(k);
[K2,E2]=ellipke(k_bar);
U=Gamma*(((R*r)^(1/2)/(2*pi*k))*(((2-k^2)*(K1))-(2*E1))-((R*r)^(1 /2)/(2*pi*k_bar))*(((2-k_bar^2)*(K2))-(2*E2)));

Ur=(1/r)*(diff(U,y));
Uy=(1/r)*(diff(U,r));
Gamma = -0.0045;                     
a_t= 0.0053;                        
R= .02;                                                                  
Y= 0.018;
[r,y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:1);
u= subs(Ur);
v= subs(Uy);
figure
quiver(r,y,u,v)
startx = 0.1:0.1:1;
starty = ones(size(startx));
streamline(x,y,u,v,startx,starty)
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you read the error message? You're dividing by zero,I think the `1/r`

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I changed it [r,y] = meshgrid(0.01:0.1:1,0:0.1:1); But the result still not correct

Comment: Again, reading the error message says `x` is not defined.

You might want to try a simpler example that you can definitely get working then build it up

Comment: Thank you. I already correct that. But the problem that the result is not correct. I got the plot but it is not correct.

Comment: Why is that plot wrong? It looks like you're just following the example from the `streamline` documentation. Does that make sense in your case? Have you tried denser streamlines. Try `startx = 0.1:0.001:1;` and you'll see that the lines follow the `quiver` plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mesh includes `0`, so you get a division by zero error. You have two options.

Get rid of the zeros in you mesh. For example:

```
...
[r,y] = meshgrid(eps:0.1:1,eps:0.1:1);
u = subs(Ur);
v = subs(Uy);
...
```

Or evaluate the symbolic expressions numerically such that division by zero results in floating point `NaN`:

```
...
[r,y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:1);
u = eval(Ur);
v = eval(Uy);
...
```

Since you're plotting numerically, it probably makes more sense to do the latter. Most Matlab plot functions ignore `NaN` values (not sure about `quiver` and `streamline` in particular). You also have an undefined variable in your last line – did you mean `r` instead of `x`?

Comment: Thanks, I did the second one but still the result not correct

Comment: @Ali: You really need to give proper feedback. "still the result not correct" does not give me any information. Spend some time understanding the error messages, learning to debug, and reading the documentation. I did not get any errors when I ran your code for the second case in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know how to add photo in comment. So, I add the result as photo to the question. This photo shows the result. Also, I meant r instead of x. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I got the correct plot. The problem was that I forgot to put minus sign for Uy=(1/r)*(diff(U,r)). it should be Uy=(-1/r)*(diff(U,r))

Comment: @Ali: Good to hear. If my answer was helpful, please be sure to [upvote/accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thank you so much. I did, it was very helpful